# Driver Find Element

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I'm trying to click on a button but my code doesn't work. This is the button.

```
<button class="artdeco-button artdeco-button--secondary artdeco-button--3 mr1"> </button>
```

The ways I tried:
 `driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".mr1").click()`

`driver.find_element_by_class_name("artdeco-button").click()`

The error I get every time is : `selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: Element <span class="search-vertical-filter__dropdown-trigger-text mr1"> is not clickable at point (151,80) because another element <div class="modal-wormhole-overlay "> obscures it`

Can someone help me?

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: I updated the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: Element <span class="search-vertical-filter__dropdown-trigger-text mr1"> is not clickable at point (151,80) because another element <div class="modal-wormhole-overlay "> obscures it
```

Because there is one more tag avaiable with class name mr1 use tag name as well.

driver.find_element_by_css_selector("tagname.classname").click()

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button.mr1").click()
```

OR

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"button.mr1"))).click()
```